# Get value in column from matrix of row numbers

Tags: r, data.table

Here is the data setup:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(42)
pos_mat <- data.table(c1 = sample(1:1000), c2 =  sample(1:1000), c3 = sample(1:1000))
data    <- data.table(value = rnorm(1000), other_stuff = rnorm(1000))
```

The table looks like this:

```
> pos_mat
    c1  c2  V3
1: 915 849 990
2: 937  63 439
3: 286 819 699
4: 828 538 887
5: 640 498 831

996: 118 793 783
997: 777 670 617
998: 579 195 643
999: 351 728 221
1000: 834 742 244
```

and:

```
> data
           value  other_stuff
   1: -0.6013830  0.617336710
   2: -0.1358161 -0.004541141
   3: -0.9872728 -0.091256360
   4:  0.8319250  0.399959375
   5: -0.7950595  0.588901657

 996: -0.3757455  0.264323016
 997: -1.0417354 -1.355822276
 998:  0.6976674  0.359071548
 999: -0.1444488 -1.708252839
1000:  0.4985434 -0.635928277
```

Now each element in pos_mat responds to a row number in data. I would a new data.table that has the same dimensions as pos_mat, but instead of having row numbers it hold the corrosponding value from data.

I.e. pos_mat[1,.(c1)] has the value 915. In data[915,.(value)] = 0.1702369 and I would like this to stored in the new object.

I feel that something like:

```
new <- pos_mat
n <- nrow(pos_mat)
for(i in n) new[i,] <- data[unlist(pos_mat[1,]), value]
```

Should work, but it keeps telling me the dimensions are wrong.

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Comment: If you want to keep the same dimensions this should work `new <- cbind(data$value[pos_mat$c1], data$value[pos_mat$c2], data$value[pos_mat$c3])`

Comment: @EtienneMoerman I see your idea, I have 100.000 columns... that would would be some typ'ing...

Comment: `data[pos_mat$c1, .(rowNum=pos_mat$c1, value)]` also appears to work.

Comment: @Repmat you're right. There probably a nice apply function that works for this. I'll have try of Imo's solution doesn't work

Comment: Here's an `lapply` method for repeating this over many columns: `do.call(data.table, lapply(pos_mat, function(x) data[x, .(rowNum=x, value)]))`. The variables are named according to the variables in pos_mat.

Comment: @Imo maybe I am missing something, but it throws and error about FUN missing

Comment: If you want to vectorize this, I would suggest you work with matrices. Something like the following should work `res <- as.matrix(pos_mat) ; indx <- unlist(pos_mat) ; res[] <- data[indx, value]`

Comment: I don't think you need `lapply` or any looping. Try: `out <- data$value[unlist(pos_mat)]; out <- data.table(matrix(out,nrow=nrow(pos_mat))); colnames(out) <- colnames(pos_mat)`. The first line does the job. The other two just turns that `vector` to a `data.table` with the same column names as `pos_mat`.

Comment: @Repmat I think I just fixed the error, but working with matrices as suggested by others may be faster.

Comment: Though the most efficient `data.table` way would probably be using `set` as in `for (j in names(pos_mat)) set(pos_mat, j = j, value = data[pos_mat[[j]], value])`

Comment: @DavidArenburg that returns NULL

Comment: @aichao That seems to do the trick... even if sub memory efficent

Comment: No it isn't. Print `pos_mat`. It was updated by reference.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I just checked  all.equal(out, pos_mat) [1] TRUE... My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a smaller data set

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(42)
pos_mat <- data.table(c1 = sample(1:10), c2 =  sample(1:10), c3 = sample(1:10))
data <- data.table(value = rnorm(10), other_stuff = rnorm(10))
```

If you want a `data.table` solution, you could use `set` and update `pos_dat` (or any other data set) in place, something like

```
for (j in names(pos_mat)) set(pos_mat, j = j, value = data[pos_mat[[j]], value])
pos_mat
#             c1         c2         c3
#  1:  1.8951935  1.3201133  1.8951935
#  2:  1.2146747 -1.7813084 -0.2842529
#  3: -2.6564554 -0.1719174 -0.1719174
#  4: -0.3066386 -0.2842529 -1.7813084
#  5: -2.4404669 -2.6564554  0.6359504
#  6: -0.1719174  1.8951935 -2.6564554
#  7:  1.3201133 -2.4404669  1.2146747
#  8:  0.6359504  0.6359504  1.3201133
#  9: -0.2842529 -0.3066386 -0.3066386
# 10: -1.7813084  1.2146747 -2.4404669
```

---

Or using matrices (using a fresh `pos_mat` data set)

```
res <- data[unlist(pos_mat), value]
dim(res) <- dim(pos_mat)
res
#             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
#  [1,]  1.8951935  1.3201133  1.8951935
#  [2,]  1.2146747 -1.7813084 -0.2842529
#  [3,] -2.6564554 -0.1719174 -0.1719174
#  [4,] -0.3066386 -0.2842529 -1.7813084
#  [5,] -2.4404669 -2.6564554  0.6359504
#  [6,] -0.1719174  1.8951935 -2.6564554
#  [7,]  1.3201133 -2.4404669  1.2146747
#  [8,]  0.6359504  0.6359504  1.3201133
#  [9,] -0.2842529 -0.3066386 -0.3066386
# [10,] -1.7813084  1.2146747 -2.4404669
```

Both should be efficient, but the `data.table` one probably more memory efficient

Comment: These are nice solutions, on my real data the first solution is faster... But the second solution worked fast enough (and is perhaps a tad simpler).